# Set attributes of ServletContext in Spring 3.2 MVC configuration

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-mvc

I'm stuck on a pretty simple task: how to set ServletContext attributes in Spring MVC 3.2 configuration?

I found that something similar can be done with ServletContextPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer, but from Spring 3.1 this is considered as deprecated:
"***Deprecated***. in Spring 3.1 in favor of PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer in conjunction with StandardServletEnvironment."

This doesn't tell me much, since I don't know how to do it with StandardServletEnvironment.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [ServletContextAttributeExporter](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextAttributeExporter.html) for this. Define a `ServletContextAttributeExporter` bean as below in your configuration file and set its `attributes` property to a map of `key and value` pairs that you want to put into `ServletContext`:

```xml
<bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
    <property name="attributes">
        <map>
            <entry key="myKey" value="1" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can you please provide the code how this is done with pure java configuration?
And how do I get the attribute in the jsp?

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a *.properties file somewhere in your class path, e.g. `/myprops.properties`.
2. Add a property-placeholder to your context-config:

   `<context:property-placeholder location="myprops.properties"/>`

or, if you are using java config:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:myprops.properties")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    ...
}
```

Comment: When you mean "context-config", is the `application-context.xml` right?

Comment: Thank you. Once I put `<context:...>` in `application-context.xml`, plus `@PropertySource("classpath:myprops.properties")`, can I do `@Value()` to get the contents of `myprops.properties` for file I/O?

Comment: @user75782131 Not "plus", use either `<context:..` if you are using xml-config or `@PropertySource` if you are using Java-config. In both config styles you can use `@Value` after that. Btw.: When using `@Value` you can also specify default values used when the property isn't found in the prop-source: `@Value("${hfs.datastore:/var/opt/datastore/hfs}") String datastore)` will use `/var/opt/...` if property `hfs.datastore` isn't found.