# How to Create Service class Object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jsf

I am using **ehcache** in my project so when server start data of few table will be loaded into the cache ..in my application i am using Spring,Hibernate,JSF
I m using this configurationin **applicationCOntext.xml** file

```
<bean id="cacheManager"  class="com.ccc.service.cache.CacheManager" init-method="init">
        <property name="delay" value="${timer.delay}" />
    </bean>   
 <bean id="companyCache" class="com.ccc.service.cache.clients.ValidCacheClient"/>

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.ccc.spring" />
        <context:annotation-config />
        <context:spring-configured />
```

In Jsf Managed Bean i am creating Object of Service class like this

```
    @ManagedProperty(value = "#{GlobalDataService}")
    static GlobalDataService globalDataService;
```

But in **ValidCacheClient.java** how to create object of Service class? **ValidCacheClient.java** is not a manged class so how to create the Object of Service class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

- Inject the necessary beans to be known from JSF as `ServletContext` attributes, so these beans will be treat by JSF as application scoped attributes. You can do this using Spring [`ServletContextAttributeExporter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/support/ServletContextAttributeExporter.html):

  ```xml
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextAttributeExporter">
      <property name="attributes">
          <map>
              <entry key="globalDataService" value-ref="GlobalDataService" />
          </map>
      </property>
  </bean>
  ```

  Then you can inject it without problems in JSF:

  ```
  @ManagedProperty(value = "#{globalDataService}")
  GlobalDataService globalDataService; //no need to be static
  ```
- Let Spring container manage the lyfecycle of JSF managed beans. With this approach, you may inject the springs beans using `@Autowired`. This is covered in Spring 3 + JSF 2 tutorials. Still, note that if you do this, you will lose access to JSF 2 view scope (crucial when working with ajax requests in the same view) because [Spring still cannot support it](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-6543). But this can be solved by creating a custom implementation for view scope, like [Cagatay's](http://cagataycivici.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/port-jsf-2-0s-viewscope-to-spring-3-0/)

IMO I would use the latter approach rather than the former.

More info:

- [Set attributes of ServletContext in Spring 3.2 MVC configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20148259/1065197)
- [Mkyong tutorial to integrate Spring 3 and JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-spring-hibernate-integration-example/)
- [Bean properties are shared across different sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17278376/1065197)
- [Integration jsf, spring, hibernate. How to inject Spring beans into JSF managed beans?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23638664/1065197)

Comment: I am ok with inbjecting service class into JSFManagedBean i want to inject it non managed bean class how to do it?

Comment: @askkuber read the tutorial I've posted. There are plenty tutorials on the net about it as well. Links in answers are not for decoration purpose, they're intended to add complementary info to the answer and to not reinvent the wheel for long explanations.

Comment: @askkuber answer updated. Added more relevant info for the second approach.